# Best Approach For Performance When Running Calculations On Table Values…

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, dom

**Question in summary:**

Is it faster to get a table rows sum by using jquery:filter class and iterate through each row value…

Or

Is it faster to maintain a dictionary key/value pair reflecting the table data & iterate through the dictionary instead?

(The number of rows for this application will be in the 3-30 range.)

**The verbose details:**

I have a table with 5 columns.  2 columns contain number inputs.  3 columns contain number outputs.

Total number of rows grows or shrinks depending on user add/deleting items.

Each time user makes a change to any single row entry number input, the script must make calculations & update the values of  all other entries on every row.

Because the value of all outputs are in ratio to each other, the script must iterate through each row, and recalculate the outputs on every change.

The calculations require:

- The sum of the row entries of one column.
- The individual inputs of each row of 2 of the columns.
- The total number of rows.

The script is written in javascript.

The outputs are displayed in jquerymobile/html.

The script maintains a unique row_id for each row entry.

I'd like the outputs to update realtime… meaning as the user is adjusting a slider input, the outputs update automatically… and do it with as little lag as possible.

With that in mind...

**Here's the question:**

For performance what is the best approach to make the calculations & update the DOM?

**A)**

- Use jquery:filter by class to get the values of the entries for each row.
- Iterating through each entry to get the sum.
- Then iterate through each row entry, make the calculations for each row, then update the DOM for the 3 outputs.

Or

**B)**

- Maintain a dictionary key/value pair (using the row_id as the key).  Each time a row is added/deleted, the dictionary gets updated.
- Maintain a separate sum variable, updating it each time an input is changed and/or a row is deleted.
- Maintain a separate number of rows variable, update each time a row is added/deleted.
- Iterate through the dictionary items to make the calculations.
- Update the DOM using the #row_id from the dictionary.

Or

**C)**

Something obvious I haven't thought of…

Approach B is a lot more work.  Overall I suspect there is a much more elegant solution I'm not considering??

Comment: searching the dom won't be as performant but number of rows should also be considered when deciding on approach

Comment: Number of rows should be in the 3-30 range or so.

Comment: probably small enough not to worry unless you have problems